# Magento 2 + How to import the custom city collection from the database into a dropdown (for the city textarea)

Tags: magento2, php, model, resource-model, drop-downs

I'm a bit confused with creating a city dropdown with my custom cities. I have already imported the cities into a table and also created the Model, ResourceModel, Collection. Now I need to get those cities into a dropdown.

Below image is the table of my custom cities:

[image: cities]

Below is my code to implement the 'getAllOptions()' function:

```
namespace Talliance\SwyftShippingMethod\Model\Customer\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
use Talliance\SwyftShippingMethod\Model\ResourceModel\SrilankanCity\CollectionFactory as SrilankanCityCollectionFactory;

class SrilankanCity extends AbstractSource
{

   protected $_srilankanCityCollectionFactory;

   protected $_logger;

   public function __construct
   (
       SrilankanCityCollectionFactory $srilankanCityCollectionFactory,
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   )
   {
       $this->_srilankanCityCollectionFactory = $srilankanCityCollectionFactory;
       $this->_logger = $logger;
   }

   public function getAllOptions()
   {
       if (!$this->_options) {
           $this->_options = $this->_createCitiesCollection()->toOptionArray();
           $this->_logger->log(100, print_r($this->_options, true));
       }
       return $this->_options;
   }

   /**
    * @return \Talliance\SwyftShippingMethod\Model\ResourceModel\SrilankanCity\Collection
    */
    protected function _createCitiesCollection()
    {
        return $this->_srilankanCityCollectionFactory->create();
    }
}
```

This is my output in my debug log file:

[image]

What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use toOptionArray for your custom collection. You need to create new array with lable, value structure and then return that array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for my dropdown list by using this code 
make changes according to your code

```
<?php


namespace Talliance\SwyftShippingMethod\Model\Customer\Source;

use Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options as StoreOptions;

/**
 * Store Options for Cms Pages and Blocks
 */
class SrilankanCity extends StoreOptions
{

    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $model = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Namespace\Model\SrilankanCity');
        $collection = $model->getCollection();

        foreach ($collection as $value) {

            $options[] = ['label' => $value->srilankan_cities(), 'value' => $value->srilankan_cities()];
        }

        return $options;


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what did you implement in srilankan_cities() function and where did you put that?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I found a way to get it done.

```
namespace ...Model\Customer\Source;
...
use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
...

public function toOptionArray()
{
    /** @var \Talliance\SwyftShippingMethod\Model\ResourceModel\SrilankanCity\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->_cityCollection->create();
    $collection->getCities();
    $options = $collection->toOptionArray();
    $this->_logger->log(100, print_r($options, true));
    return $options;
}
```

Then in collection.php

```
/**
 * Get sri lankan cities
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function getCities()
{
    return $this->addFieldToSelect(array('srilankan_cities'));
}

/**
 * Retrieve option array
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return parent::_toOptionArray('id', 'srilankan_cities');
}
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: How you did this. Could you please give all steps